# How to add multiple origins in sails.js 0.12 cors.js file

Tags: node.js, typescript, cors, sails.js

Currently I have a cors.js file in my application with an origin to allow cross domain requests:

```
module.exports.cors = {
   origin: 'https://test.domain.com'
}
```

I am wondering how to add multiple origins to this file like this:

```
module.exports.cors = {
   origin: ['https://test.domain.com','https://prod.domain.com']
}
```

Is that the correct way to accomplish this? I would try to deploy this, but if it is wrong, it potentially could take down my company's portal.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Sail.js? And if so, using some older version of it (not the current version)? If so, then see the docs at https://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors#?enabling-cors, which indicates the syntax is `origin: 'example.com,api.example.com,blog.example.com,foo.com'`

Comment: Yes. That's what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package. (and check out the [Dynamic Origin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin) section)

however if you don't wish to use that package, you can always do

```
var origin = cors.origin.indexOf(req.headers.origin) > -1 ? req.headers.origin : 'yoursite.tld';
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin)
```

That checks the requesting origin, if it's in the array allow it, otherwise, set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to yoursite.tld